# Populating HTML table from multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I've two JavaScript arrays that I wish to populate HTML tables with but I can't seem to get the order of HTML tags correct to layout the table how I'm looking.

HTML:

```
<div id="dateRangeTable"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
var sensorEventCount = [41,47,36,0,0,0,0];

function popTable(array, arrayTwo) {
    var list = document.createElement('table');
    var item;
    item = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        item = document.createElement('td');
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));
        list.appendChild(item);
    }
    item.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {    
        item.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arrayTwo[i]));
        list.appendChild(item);
    }
    return list;
}
```

I'm looking it displayed with each array in line above and below each other, i.e.

```
Monday   Tuesday   Wednesday   Thursday etc.
  41       47         36           0
```

At the moment is printing like:

```
Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday
                                                  41
                                                  47
                                                  36
                                                  0
                                                  etc.
```

Comment: I didn't bother trying to run the code. But I'm thinking of creating a 2D array. `var array = [["Monday", 41], ["Tuesday", 47]]...` then just create a table using that array

Comment: aren't you missing the first tr for the table-header (weekdays) ?

Comment: As a side note, since the code is repeating for each array (=row), you could also loop through the arrays. That would have the advantage that adding an extra row, would simply mean adding one extra parameter. ES6 could make that even easier with a parameter array. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/3fbmamLo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're appending the `<tr>` to the `<table>` as a child and then adding the `<td>` to be a child of the `<table>` instead of the `<tr>`.

So your code comes out with the HTML like

```
<table>
    <td>Monday</td>
    ...
    <tr></tr>
    <td>41</td>
    ...
</table>
```

Also, you've not puting your headers in a `<tr>`

Try changing your code to be this:

```
var days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
var sensorEventCount = [41, 47, 36, 0, 0, 0, 0];

function popTable(array, arrayTwo) {
    var list = document.createElement('table');
    var headers = list.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var item = document.createElement('th');
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));
        headers.appendChild(item);
    }

    list.appendChild(headers);

    var row = list.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
    for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        var item = document.createElement('td')
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arrayTwo[j]));
        row.appendChild(item);
    }

    list.appendChild(row);
    return list;
}
```

[**Example Link**](https://jsbin.com/rodagusize/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is it possible to align the values within the cells?

Comment: @ColinShewell of course, I'm assuming you want them aligned to the right? you'd be better to do this with css, I've added a rule to the example link although you may want to just put a class on the `<td>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the new template literal:

A little sample:

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Array2Table</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="tableContent"></div>
    <script>
      var country = ["Country1", "Country2", "Country3"];
      var capital = ["City1", "City2" , "City3"];
      
      const tmpl = (country,capital) => `
          <table><thead>
          <tr><th>Country<th>Capital<tbody>
          ${country.map( (cell, index) => `
              <tr><td>${cell}<td>${capital[index]}</tr>
          `).join('')}
          </table>`;
      tableContent.innerHTML=tmpl(country, capital);
      </script> 
  </body>
  </html>
```